# How I solve Google Play Game Services: SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider?

Tags: java, android, google-play, google-play-services

I encounted permission error like this:

```
12-10 11:40:16.299: E/AndroidRuntime(1418): java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider com.google.android.gms.games.provider.GamesContentProvider from ProcessRecord{437fc7e8 1418:com.papa.games.bc/u0a276} (pid=1418, uid=10276) that is not exported from uid 10020
```

My code is like this

```
Bitmap bm = null;
try {
    bm = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), getGamesClient().getCurrentPlayer().getIconImageUri());
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    Log.i("TAG", "FileNotFoundException", e);
} catch (IOException e) {
    Log.i("TAG", "IOException", e);
}
```

How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 3):

You have to use one of the [ImageManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/images/ImageManager.html) methods to load images from Google Play Services. These handling caching and loading for you - you only need to display the returned `Drawable` or use `loadImage(imageView, uri)` to load directly into an `ImageView`.

Comment: Is there a way to not use it? How the security part in that thing work?

Comment: @Ilya_Gazman Nope. The Google Play services library directly connects to the Google Play services app (which does have permission) and requests the image, returning it back to your application.

Comment: This answer should be accepted as the correct answer. It helped me. I am just amazed that Google does not publish examples of a custom leaderboard UI (at least not that I could find).